# Is it possible to load a image without a image name?

Tags: html, image

Is it possible to load a image without the image name?
Like this:

```
<img src="http://www.example.com" />
```

The reason for only use the URL, is because there is every time an other image on the URL, so the image name is dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is!

Supposing you can use php on your server `http://www.example.com/`

If you add an `index.php` with this code:

```
<?php
    $file = '../image.jpg';
    $type = 'image/jpeg';

    header('Content-Type:'.$type);
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
?>
```

`http://www.example.com/`  is going to return an image *(with the correct MIME)* that can be read this way: `<img src="http://www.example.com" />`

Answer (score 4):

Yes, certainly.

Keep in mind that there's a difference between a file system and an HTTP request/response.  When you make a request for something like this:

```
http://www.example.com/image.jpg
```

It *looks like* you're requesting a file.  But what you're actually doing is requesting an HTTP resource.  The web server receives that request, and very likely in this case translates it into a file system path.  The web server loads that file into memory, then issues an HTTP response with the contents of the file (and HTTP headers for that type of file).

The point is, all of the file system interaction happens server-side, completely unknown to the web browser or whatever client is making the request.  Whether that data came from a file or a database entry or some other server-side location makes no difference.  As long as the resulting HTTP response contains the data and HTTP headers, there's no difference.

So you can just as easily request something like this:

```
http://www.example.com/someHandler?id=123
```

And maybe that server-side handler has some code to fetch a specific piece of data based on that `id` value.  Maybe that data is an image.  As long as the response is correct for an image, the browser/client won't know the difference.

There's no concept of a "name" (in the sense of a file name) in HTTP requests, just a resource URL.  That URL can be anything.  It's the server-side application's responsibility to return the data and headers accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If a request would be made to http://www.example.com and the response would be some kind of image then yes. URL does not ceratinly have to have `.jpg` or `.png` or some other image file extension. But you have to know the URL you are performing a request to.